# Overflow while converting variant of type (Decimal) into type (Currency) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image: Image Of error]

I have a strange problem in SQL Server 2012. I have a table with a column of type `decimal(38, 5)`.

After some calculations, `959786379036777.63000` is saved in this column without any errors, but when I select from this column, I get this error.

Sample code:

```
declare @X decimal(38, 5) = 959786379036777.63000
select @X
```

and the result is:

> Overflow while converting variant of type (Decimal) into type (Currency)

I don't have this problem in my own PC! Hope you can help me with this!

SQL Server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR) (KB3194721) 
11.0.6248.0 (X64) - Sep 23 2016 15:49:43 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Comment: Sample code you have shown obviously does not throw this mistake. Can you show actual code that can reproduce the error? Do you use custom created type?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I just attached the image of error. seems it occurs on some versions of SQL servers. No I used decimal(38, 5) directly

Comment: What is this application you are using to run queries? It is likely the cause of error, maybe doing conversion of result for some reason. SQL Server could not have produced that error as SQL Server does not even have Currency type. Try running the same in Management Studio to check.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic this is a tools for connecting to sql server. you were right when I run my code remotely on sql server there is no error. Thanks for your comment. Now I need to run my procedure on Management Studio to find the other bug!